# How to upload and save multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem with file upload control. I have a class like below:

```
public class EmployeeSuperClass
{
    //some other classes
    public DocumentsList AdditionalDocumentDetailsFields { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDocumentsTable
{
    public int EmployeeDocumentId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public bool EmployeeDocumentIsMandatory { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeDocumentName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeDocumentDescription { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^.*\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|pdf|PDF)$", ErrorMessage = "Please use an image with an extension of .jpg, .png, .pdf")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase EmployeeDocumentFileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Using this class am going to add multiple documents because one employee might produce multiple document when joining organisation, so I have created list of documents below like this:

```
public class DocumentsList
{
    public List<EmployeeDocumentsTable> documentsList { get; set; }
    public DocumentsList()
    {
        documentsList = new List<EmployeeDocumentsTable>();
    }
}
```

I want to add multiple documents to employee.
Can anybody please give an idea how to add multiple documents using an add button and after added multiple files to employee I want to save all files at once?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you add `multiple="multiple"` in you file upload control, it will support multiple selection while uploading. You should show your Controller and Views too for more clarity. Also try showing what you tried, and where it is failing. You can refer to the following links for multiple file uploads scenarios:

[Multiple File Upload 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/805195/Multiple-File-Upload-in-MVC)

[Multiple File Upload 2](http://www.itorian.com/2014/03/single-file-upload-to-multiple-file.html)